# Elasticsearch Fleet Server Outputs > Specify where agents will send data

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

Is posible to send data to an external elasticsearch deployment with fleet server?

I have tried with the [Kibana Fleet UI settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/fleet/current/fleet-settings.html) but there is no username, password field for connection, if I specify those on Advanced YAML configuration give me these error: `cannot set both api_key and username/password accessing 'elasticsearch'`

**Fleet > Settings > Outputs | Specify where agents will send data**
[image: Fleet > Settings > Specify where agents will send data]

I can see the [Kibana Fleet Settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/8.6/fleet-settings-kb.html) `xpack.fleet.outputs` > `config` described as `Extra config for that output` to set this manually but there is no example to set this `config` variable.

**Kibana version:** kibana:8.5.3

**Elasticsearch version:** elasticsearch:8.5.3

**Install method:** Elastic ECK 2.6

Comment: The answer to this question was provided here (also asked by the OP): https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/150111#issuecomment-1425925136

Comment: But since you're on ECK, you might be able to achieve what you want [by manually configuring the elasticsearch output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-elastic-agent-configuration.html#k8s-elastic-agent-set-output). You might also need to [manually create API keys](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/fleet/current/grant-access-to-elasticsearch.html#create-api-key-standalone-agent) in your remote cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Agents don't support sending the logs to remote cluster, so you won't be able to send data to any external Elasticsearch per say.
However, you can either opt for beats and provide the list of ES hosts where you want to send the logs OR use logstash to receive input from Agent and configure your output with list of ES hosts.